# Subtracting 1 in a column after a specific row in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  `Event Full` = c('SocReframeNeg',
                   'SocReframeNeg',
                   'test',
                   'SocReframeNeg',
                   'SocReframeNeg',
                   'SocImmerseNeg',
                   'SocImmerseNeg'),
  Num = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
)
```

I want to subtract 1 from `Num` for all rows after 'test', and then remove the row with 'test' from the dataframe.

This is the output:

```
solution <- data.frame(
  `Event Full` = c('SocReframeNeg',
                   'SocReframeNeg',
                   'SocReframeNeg',
                   'SocReframeNeg',
                   'SocImmerseNeg',
                   'SocImmerseNeg'),
  Num = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
)
```

Does anyone know an efficient way to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
i_test <- which(example[["Event.Full"]] == "test")
example$Num[i_test:nrow(example)] <- example$Num[i_test:nrow(example)] - 1
example <- example[-i_test, ]
example
##      Event.Full Num
## 1 SocReframeNeg   1
## 2 SocReframeNeg   2
## 4 SocReframeNeg   3
## 5 SocReframeNeg   4
## 6 SocImmerseNeg   5
## 7 SocImmerseNeg   6
```

Note that `data.frame()` has replaced the space in the column name `"Event Full"` by a dot. If you don't want this, you have to call `data.frame()` with `check.names = FALSE` like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  `Event Full` = c('SocReframeNeg',
                   'SocReframeNeg',
                   'test',
                   'SocReframeNeg',
                   'SocReframeNeg',
                   'SocImmerseNeg',
                   'SocImmerseNeg'),
  Num = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  check.names = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
library(dplyr)

example |>
  mutate(Num = Num - (row_number() > grep('test', Event.Full))) |>
  filter(Event.Full != 'test')
```

```
     Event.Full Num
1 SocReframeNeg   1
2 SocReframeNeg   2
3 SocReframeNeg   3
4 SocReframeNeg   4
5 SocImmerseNeg   5
6 SocImmerseNeg   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively in base R

```r
solution  <- example[example$Event.Full!='test',]
solution$Num <- seq(1:nrow(solution )) 
solution
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
     Event.Full Num
1 SocReframeNeg   1
2 SocReframeNeg   2
4 SocReframeNeg   3
5 SocReframeNeg   4
6 SocImmerseNeg   5
7 SocImmerseNeg   6
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr` with `cumsum(Event.Full == "test")`.

```
library(dplyr)

example |> 
    mutate(Num = if_else(cumsum(Event.Full == "test") == 1,
                         Num - 1,
                         Num
                         )
           ) |> 
    filter(Event.Full !="test")

     Event.Full Num
1 SocReframeNeg   1
2 SocReframeNeg   2
3 SocReframeNeg   3
4 SocReframeNeg   4
5 SocImmerseNeg   5
6 SocImmerseNeg   6
```